# Drop Box Like StackOverflow tag chooser

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

i need help on coding javascript to detect the up and down arrow key hits and do an event on each key hit, **without** changing the cursor position of a focused textfield kinda like the stack overflow tag chooser

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what code you already produce.

Comment: i would but it's irrelevant. i just need to know how to detect up and down arrow keys in javascript without changing the cursor position in a focused textfield

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use plugins, I would recommend the jQuery UI [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) instead of rolling your own